# changing a hexadecimal array at a particular index

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, hex

```
// if i received from a systemA 
            else if(test_addr.sin_addr.s_addr == systemA_addr.sin_addr.s_addr){ 
                    if(CHECK_STATUS ==0){
                    sendto(sock, ca, bytes_read, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&CSS_addr, sizeof(CSS_addr)); 
                    memcpy(last_systemA_msg, ca, sizeof(ca));
                    memset(ca,0,BUFLEN);                
                    for (j = 0; j < bytes_read; ++j) {
                        printf("%02x", last_systemA_msg[j]);  //02x
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }

                if(CHECK_STATUS ==1 && (strcmp(rcvd_ASR_msg,"MESSAGE_RCVD") == 0)){
                    last_systemA_msg[16] = 0x05;
                    sendto(sock, last_systemA_msg, bytes_read,0,(struct sockaddr *)&CSS_addr, sizeof(CSS_addr));
                    printf("The data is modified\n");
                    for (k = 0; k < bytes_read; ++k) {
                        printf("%02x", last_systemA_msg[k]);  //02x
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
```

I get this output of first section

```
            65210014a80d010101000001000000000000000000000000000
```

I need to modify this data and as they are hexidecimal i did it this way..

I should expect the data to be modified to

```
            65210014a80d010101000001000000050000000000000000000
```

then i need to send this complete data through socket.

But i am getting this-- ???

```
            The data is modified
            65210014230f01010100000100000000
            65210014240f01010100000100000000000000000000000000
```

Why my data are not modified although i changed the value at that position? Why it is different in length than the original data?

Comment: are you sure you are using `ox05` and not `0x05`?

Comment: There somehow is one char too much (two to few) in the data you show. Mind the length of the second "long" character sequence comapred to the other two "long" ones.

Comment: This question is unclear und inaccurate. This is not a guessing game. Word your question, then read it and imagine you have no clue what it is about. And then ask yourself: Do I get what this guy wants know?

Comment: Your last two examples are *not* the same data. One contains substring `230f` and the other `240f`. In your code, the second section beginning `if(CHECK_STATUS ==1 ...` although indented is not within the previous code block that begins `else if` which does not necessarily get executed.

Comment: @alk I am sorry for the confusion, I copied wrongly so some bits were missing. The problem mentioned by #Weather actually caused the problem. Thank you

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly it was the problem. I solved it.It is working fine now. Thank you

Comment: @bsnayak I have converted the comment you liked to an answer, please accept if it helped, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two examples are not the same data. One contains substring `230f` and the other `240f`. In your code, the second section beginning `if(CHECK_STATUS ==1 ...` although indented is not within the previous code block that begins `else if` which does not necessarily get executed.